# Karate: Replace variables in text type

Tags: karate

I need to do a replacement in the text `payload`, which contains something that is not JSON nor XML.

I wrote the following:

```
* def id = "1234"
* text payload =
"""
...several lines... 
<id>
...several lines... 
"""
* replace payload.id = id
* print payload
```

I know this works, but my question is if my approach is correct or there is better way because when I'm working with JSON or XML I just put #(id) in the body and it is automatically replaced.

Thanks.

Comment: your approach is correct. in the future we may support `hello ${foo}` within back-ticks JS / ES6 - see: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide